# How can I parse json response

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

This is the json response how can I parse it?

[
    {
     "id":"35",
     "name":"Jalsa"
    }
 ]

[
    {
     "id":"32",
     "name":"Nandhini"
    }
]

Comment: The code i posted does not work?

Comment: This is not a valid json response again. Is it 2 different responses ?

Comment: Please help me The url is this http://www.coolqs.com/android/listofQueues.php?mobile=1114445557

Comment: This is not valid json. You can check it at http://jsonlint.com/ for yourself

Answer (score 3):

There is a class from apple which is called

> NSJSONSerialization

You can use the following method to parse your json data

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```

For more Info refer the apple doc : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

edit:

I don't know how do you make the request eg. NSURLConnection

assumed you have filled your _recievedData in your

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

method

And you can get your array like this

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   NSArray *recivedArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_receivedData options:0 error:nil];
}
```

If you need more help about how to receive data you can find here examples https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Comment: thank u but response from json is array inside dictionary again array inside dictionary. please help me

Answer (score 1):

We use **NSArray** when the expression is between "[" "]"
We use **NSDictionary** when an expression is inside "{" "}"

In our case the json is an Array containing 2 Dictionaries. Each dictionary contains 2 key-value pairs.

```
 NSError *e = nil;
 NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: 
 NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
 if (e!=nil) {
     // Handle error
     return;
 }
 for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonArray)
 {        
     NSString *theID = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
     NSLog(@"ID:%@" , theID);

     NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
     NSLog(@"Name: %@" , name);
 }
```

Comment: thank u but response from json is array inside dictionary again array inside dictionary. please help me George

Comment: Ok can you tell me how the original json is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONKit if you need to support iOS 4.x, as NSJSONSerialization is only available since iOS 5.x.

JSONKit has awesome performance too. Check the comparisons on their project page at GitHub.